# How to use my classes as mapped by EF 6 stored procedures return type?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a database and a set of stored procedures. I want to use only stored procedures to access database. In model browser's function import I can create new complex type based on stored procedure return value, but I want to reuse classes that I already have. Complex types dropdown list consists of types generated by Entity Framework only. Adding `[ComplexType]` attribute to my classes doesn't seem to change that. If I change return type manually in `MyEntities.Context.cs` it will be changed back after I update model from database, which is no so good.

Comment: You don't need to create complex types. You can just use the "Entities" drop down to select the existing object you want to return.

Comment: Entities dropdown list is empty in my case. How can I fill it with my classes then?

Comment: In the designer, you should see the entities. Have you not add any entities?

Comment: You mean from a database? No, I want to use classes from another C# project and use EF to map stored procedures only.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning the return value of an `sp`, you can use the Entities drop-down and select the type you want to be returned:

[image]

As you can see, I have an entity defined and I can then select it from the drop-down.

It might be worth noting that this entity was generated by EF - you cannot use classes you created yourself or from a third party dll unless you use the `Complex` type object then manually map them by hand or use some tool like `AutoMapper`.